# Does Dropbox have file count limit?

Tags: file, cloud, storage, dropbox

I've just symlinked several of my home subdirectories (.vim, .purple, .Skype, mostly append-only catalogs of fine-grained historical data) into Dropbox folder for hassle-free backup, and now watching Dropbox uploading 20,000+ (400 Mb worth) of files, which is well within my space quota.

I'm pretty sure it will succeed, but I've realized that I know nothing of **file count** limits of Dropbox.

Does any one have any experience with respect to this very parameter?

I will also write to Dropbox support and post their answer here.

UPD. Success. «You added 33697 files» is said at the Events page.

Comment: Feel like this belongs in Superuser (I know, its an old question - just a house cleaning comment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dropbox doesn't impose a limit on the number of files.

Answer (score 12):

It DOES have a limit in 2 senses as I have just discovered.

The first is the total number of files, which Dropbox itself states that above 300.000 files the performance of Dropbox will decline noticeably. Have a read here: http://www.businessinsider.com/maximimum-number-of-files-dropbox-can-handle-2013-9

Also there is a maximum of files that can be contained in an unshared folder that is than shared. I don't know what the exact limit is, but it gave me an error saying "This folder has too many files to share at once. Please move some files out, try a subfolder, or contact support for assistance." The folder I am trying to share currently contains just above 100.000 files.

Comment: quite interesting. and what would be your solution to share that many files? What's your application that leads you to such a troublesome experience? ;)

Comment: You also cannot unshare a folder with high file counts, which can pose potential security hassles (i.e. having to remove files from a share just to revoke one user's access). Not insurmountable, just annoying. It would also appear to all synced devices as a deletion, so you should make sure to restore the files to the folder within hours, to ensure they're still maintained in the local Dropbox .cache and don't need a full re-sync (or block them from syncing during the interim).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it does have a limit. I have been struggling for almost a year requesting support and AT THE END they admitted that there are limitations. I guess I have contributed to them admitting the 300,000 (originally they put 500,000) limit. But this is not the main problem. Worse is that when you upload more than 500,00 (I had 2 million; 1,7 T with 10T purchased) you cannot get them back! Right! Because downloading does not work, it says "zip file too large", sharing to another dropbox does not, it says "too many files", calculating folder size also does not work. Summary, the business account and the unlimited storage is without a meaning.

Comment: I've recently discovered this issue as well.  As of Dec 2022, Dropbox still only supports 300K files.  Which is nothing in today's world (I have 1.2 million).  I have 20+ years of archived pictures, movies and music.  This applies to business accounts too.  Dropbox cannot be taken seriously for heavy business users.  If you're a photographer with lots of clients then forget Dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

For the problem:

"This folder has too many files to share at once. Please move some files out, try a subfolder, or contact support for assistance."

As posted on dropbox forums:

https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201290889-I-need-to-share-a-folder-with-a-lot-of-files-in-it

Folders with over 10,000 files wont share due to technical reasons, once shared they can host over 10,000 files tho.
To resolve your problem...
move the files out of the folder
share the folder
move the files back into the folder

Answer (score 2):

Yes Dropbox has file limits, however they're more of a "if you pass this threshold, you'll run into problems" than true hard limits. Also common sense should say it's generally a bad idea to *not* put limits on your software; safe to assume there are limits with Dropbox.

According to [Dropbox's documentation](https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/space-storage/file-storage-limit), there is a 300,000 file sync threshold. 300k isn't bad, but when you have 500k or higher, performance will not only decline but you can mess up the the ability to remove that file or folder from Dropbox's servers. [Another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20243330/415763) suggests issues with sharing folders containing a high number of files.

I have found that out the hard way by accidentally syncing 4.3 million files from folders that were not de-selected during selective sync. After deleting the folder locally, then attempting to delete from Dropbox.com, the folder became stuck in a state of halfway being deleted. I cannot upload a folder with the same name, and have waited over 24 hours for the folder to be permanently removed from Dropbox.com's servers without any luck.

From Dropbox Support directly:

> From our experience, deletions of this scale require a process that
>   can take some time to complete from our side.

Advice #1: **Try to avoid uploading more than 500,000 files.**

Advice #2: If you have a large folder to delete, **delete sub-folders in small groups so that they avoid the giant deletion process**. My theory here is that if they've got a bunch of workers constantly running deletion processes, so they can only do some many deletes at one time. If a folder is too large, it may miss the first & faster deletion queue and be put into a different processing queue for anomaly folders that have too many files... or it could even have something to do trying to delete across clusters. All in all I've had more success deleting smaller sized folders than large ones.